# Create and initialize Python lists in different ways give different results

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I was developing some code involving Python lists. I have initialized them in two manners:

```
1. a1 = [[0] * 5] * 5
2. a2 = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]
```

When I try to assign values to the elements this is the result:

```
a1[0][0] = 1
a2[0][0] = 1

a1 => [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

a2 => [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Python is keeping the same (x and y) references for all objects in the list for a1, but for a2, individual references are used. Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/16768672)

Comment: also, your results are backwards.  a1 will have the change in all sublists.  a2 will have the change in only one sublist

Comment: Yes, this behavior is expected

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior. When you do `list * 5`, Python makes a shallow five-fold copy. The added lists are not new lists that happen to have the same contents; *they point to the exact same list in memory*.

```py
a = [list1, list2]
b = a*2
# Here, b equals [list1, list2, list1, list2].
# If you append something to b[0],
# you are implicitly appending it to b[2] as well,
# since they are the exact same list.
```

Comment: no, it *doesn't make a copy at all*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Perhaps I should have been more specific: what I mean with "copy", is that only the references to all the elements are copied. The lists inside the toplevel list are not shallow-copied, their references are just taken and duplicated to make the list 5x as long.